# How to remove the items from list in python based on other list

Tags: python, django

I have

`list1  = [var1,var2,var3,var4,var5]`

and other

`list2 = [var4, var2]`

Now i want to subtract them so that final result is

```
list1 = [var1,var3,var5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumin lists don't have duplicate items,

```
list(set(list1)-set(list2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension this way:

```
l1 = [var1,var2,var3,var4,var5]
l2 = [var4, var2]

diff = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]
```

Comment: you could add `l2 = set(l2)` to speed up `x not in l2` lookup.

Comment: yes sure - i know, but sometimes it is not so important - so i just tried to provide an option for OP

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your lists in sets and get difference between them

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1, 3]
list1 = set(list1)
list2 = set(list2)
list1.difference(list2)
OUTPUT: set([2, 4])
```